# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch when using google device access

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#redirect_uri_mismatch

When authorising account after it is returning

> Authorization Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Answer (score 0):

The redirect_uri is used to tell Google where you would like the response for the authorization flow to be returned to.   It must exactly match one that you have added in Google developer console.

Go to Google developer console for your application and ensure that you have properly configured the redirect uri in your Oauth2 client.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to get Nest devices athorised to your project? If so, I was trying to do the same on the device acces console. Week of trying with google (about non existing) support.) I notices that there was a guide, which magically works[

enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiCdo.png)

Follow that guide!